# Pandas mode function

Tags: pandas, numpy

Pandas and numpy mode function provides most occurring value across row or column based on axis defined on entire dataframe.
But is there way to find most occurring value in entire dataframe irrespective of column or rows?

Comment: stack the data: `df.stack().mode()`, same for numpy `array.ravel()` also flatten your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute `mode` over the entire dataframe, you can use [`mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) from `scipy.stats` module.

> **axis** (int or None, optional)
> Axis along which to operate. Default is 0. **If None, compute over the whole array a.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

np.random.seed(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 10)))
res = mode(df, axis=None)
```

Output:

```
>>> res
ModeResult(mode=array([8]), count=array([14]))

>>> res.mode[0]
8

>>> res.count[0]
14
```